# How do I print Excel without hidden cells with C#?

Tags: c#, excel, invisible

I'm using C# and I want to make an Excel file without hidden cells.

I did some actions to hide rows, and I want to make an Excel file with that, but the Excel file showed full rows with hidden rows.

Is there any options or tip to hide invisible rows?

```
List_Com.Sheets[0].Rows[i].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Check for the rows .Hidden property, not the .Visible property.

Answer (score 0):

Try also to set the row height to 0.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16627667)

Comment: @RomanoZumbé On the contrary, this will hide the rows in question, and it will prevent them from being printed, while it is a poor answer it does answer the question. Not all question have to provide code samples stating *exactly* how to solve the problem, a push in *the right direction* is still an answer.

Comment: This is an answer. It is a *low quality* answer, but not a *very low quality* answer worthy of summary deletion.

Comment: When MS Excel hide a row, what it does behind in the file format is to set the row height to 0. So making the row visible false or setting the row height to 0 are just equivalent.